# I can't move my JLabel with Key Binding?

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings

I am trying to make a game in Java where pressing spacebar moves the box in the window. I am using Key Binding to accomplish this task. The problem is that I can't figure out how to use an ActionListener on the box itself, which is a JLabel. Here is the code below:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction; 
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class Game {

private static JFrame frame     = new JFrame();
private static JPanel gamePanel = new JPanel();
private static Action playerAction = new PlayerListener();
private static JLabel box = new JLabel();
private static int x = 250;
private static int y = 250;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    frame.add(boxPanel());
    frame.setTitle("Block Game");
    frame.setSize(500,500);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setFocusable(true);

    box.addActionListener(playerAction);

    frame.setVisible(true);

}

static JPanel boxPanel() {
    ImageIcon boxIcon = new ImageIcon("box.png");
    box.setIcon(boxIcon);

    box.setSize(30,30);
    box.setLocation(x,y);

    box.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SPACE"), "doPlayerAction");
    box.getActionMap().put("doPlayerAction", playerAction);

    gamePanel.setLayout(null);
    gamePanel.add(box);
    frame.add(gamePanel);

    return gamePanel;   
}

static class PlayerListener extends AbstractAction {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        System.out.println("SPACEBAR");

    }

}
}
```

I tried changing the box to a JButton and working with that instead, but I have found that "SPACEBAR" only prints out when I click on the box itself. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: instead of extending `AbstractAction` implement `KeyListener`.[follow this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077168/moving-jlabel-with-arrow-keys)

Comment: @jackjay KeyBindings don't suffer from the focus related issues as KeyListener does and represented a reusable function of work which could be applied to other input methods, unlike KeyListener and it's more likely a layout issue

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks. But as OP said output is coming when OP clicks the label, so i thought it might be focus problem.

Comment: @jackjay Since there are no `MouseListener`s in the code, I'm not sure how that works :P

Comment: @jackjay It is, partly, a focus related issue, but `KeyListener` won't solve it any better :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "core" problem revolves around `box.getInputMap()`, change it to something more like `box.getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW)` which will mean that the API will respond to key events whenever the window has focus, regardless what other components might have focus.

I'd also suggestsomething more like `box.getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0), "doPlayerAction")`, as the mechanism which `KeyStroke` uses to parse `String` to a `KeyStroke` is more complicated then it might seem, normally requiring additional information like `pressed`, `released` or `typed`, it's just easier to use the virtual keys

I would also bind the keys to the `gamePanel` as a general preference, as it should be the container making decisions about what to do, but that's just me.

Have a look at [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks man! I will definitely follow your suggestions here :)